# React Font Awesome styles from StyleSheet not working

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am using React FontAwesome package to use FontAwesome icons in my React project. Something peculiar is happening, that is:

If I use a reference from the StyleSheet.create reference:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  ...
  style={styles.someStyle}
  ...
/>
```

that doesn't work. However, Object literals with the style (which is not a recommended practice in React) do work:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
      ...
      style={{color:"red"}}
      ...
    />
```

what could I be doing wrong / having wrong in my setup?

Comment: what's your definition of `styles.someStyle`?

Comment: imagine, the same:

 `someStyle:{color:"red"}`